# How do I create a new text file with a new name from a phpscript everytime it is executed

Tags: php, scripts, pipe

I use a [**Php script**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1119994/) which is actually for sending sms from the terminal using an online sms service  [**160by2**](http://www.160by2.com/)

What it does is opens the terminal,asks for the number then the sms and it is sent...

Now i want the text in that sms to be copied to a new file everytime.

for example like text1.txt then text2.txt and it goes on incrementing every time.

If its not possible from php script then may be i can rite a shell script that first executes the php script and then makes the new file with some command and copies the text in the sms into that file.

I want to know that command( i guess pipelining is also used) and also,how to make the file name different everytime?

I don't know shell scripting.

but in a normal programing language,like c/c++/java,the way would be a loop in which a variable is incremented everytime and then passed as a parameter to the name..is anything like this possible in shell scripting?

Comment: ... and this has what to do with Ubuntu? You need to post this on scripting ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind...this script runs in ubuntu...and the part i want is how to create a file to paste the content of terminal in it..which is normally done in shellscripting which is related to ubuntu...thats why :) ;)

Comment: shell script just means that it is written in bourne or bash shell. you can add a shebang to your php script too and chmod it and you can execute it like any other executable file. you need to be more specific if you want a certain bash feature explained.

Comment: @Ysangkok...the php file is already executable...thats how i execute it in the terminal..m confused about whether the "make a txtfile and copy the conents into it" should be implemented in the php script or through a shell script..and in either case..how..

Comment: in php it's pretty easy, you can use file_put_contents(). it's easy in bash too, i'll show you shortly

Comment: thanx a lot! waiting! ;)

Comment: Nirmik: instead of a sequence like `1, 2, ..`, will a date/time do, like `text - 2012-08-21 074401`?

Comment: @izx...yeah that will do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script should be modified to do two additional things:

1. Generate a unique filename for the text message (based on date, time, etc.)
2. Write the number `$phno` and message `$msg` to this file

We can do the former using the PHP `date` function, and the latter using the `file_put_contents` function.

All you need to do is insert these two lines of code after the phone number and message have been entered:

```
$textfilename="text ".date("Y-m-d His").".txt";
file_put_contents ($textfilename, $phno."\n".$msg."\n");
```

- Sample output, in file `text 2012-08-21 195239.txt`:

  ```
  1800LOLCATS
  ICANHAZCHEEZBURGER?
  ```

Comment: i'll add those lines in the same php script m using? and where will these files be created? how do i define a path to them?

Comment: Yes, same PHP script. They are created in the same directory as the script. To define a path, just add the full path in front of "$textfilename"s value.

Comment: adding the path in this fashion- `$textfilename=/home/username/folder/"text"...` or `$textfilename=/home/username/folder"text"...` did not work...the script doesnt run at all! it exits..and als this file was not created in the same one as the script...it was created under `/home/nirmik` whereas my script is under `/home/nirmik/Apps`

Comment: @Nirmik, it needs to be quoted, e.g. `$textfilename="/home/username/folder/text ".date..."`

Comment: okay done...just one more thing...can i have only the hour and minutes in the time part?

Answer (score 2):

here's a php script that writes a file named using the unix timestamp:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
file_put_contents("file" . ((int) microtime(true)) . ".txt", file_get_contents("/proc/cpuinfo"));
?>
```

if you want fill the file from i.e. stdin, change /proc/cpuinfo to php://stdin

here's a shell script that does the same as the original php script

```
#!/bin/sh
cat /proc/cpuinfo | tee "file`date +%s`.txt" > /dev/null
```

you can chmod +x both of these and execute them

Comment: in the php script,where will this file be created? and how do i specify a location to it if i want to?

Comment: the file will be created in the working directory of the script. if you want another directory, just prepend it as usual. i.e. you can replace `"file" ...` with `"/tmp/file" ...` and it is always going to be saved in `/tmp`

Comment: well it has created a weird txt file- http://paste.ubuntu.com/1120131/

Comment: i mean i added that line to the earlier php script...

Comment: the processor information you see is content from /proc/cpuinfo. if you want other content in your log file, just change the path. if you want to determine what to write from the STDOUT from another script, you can for example replace "cat /proc/cpuinfo" with "./myscript.sh" and the output of that script will go to your log file

Comment: i dint get it? i want the text that i type as the sms to be copied in that file! i could not see it anywhere :/ I dont want any logfile!

Comment: but where do you type the text? on stdin? then you can replace "cat /proc/cpuinfo" with just "cat". in that case, you need to end your message with a new line and then press control-d.

Comment: okay...let me try that replacing part

Comment: i type the message in the terminal :/

Comment: replacing /proc/cpuinfo by the path to the phpscript just created the complete php script again and adding a ./ before the path to the php script created an empty file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4322/discussion-between-ysangkok-and-nirmik)